# Oracle update query ignore primary constraint

Tags: oracle

I have a table AreaUser like below.

```
area   user
------------
area2  user1
area2  user2
area3  user1
```

(area,user) is a pk

I execute a query like below

```
update areatable
set user = 'user2'
where user = 'user1'
```

Primary key constraint error thrown for the first row update and the third row is not updated. How do i ignore the first row error and keep going with the updating the third row
or
how can i find if the (area,user) combination is already there in table just before updating that row.

Hope i stated the question clearly with this example. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `NOT EXISTS`, E.g.

```
Update AreaTable
   Set User = 'user2'
 Where User = 'user1'
   And Not Exists (Select 1
                     From AreaTable CheckAreaTable
                    Where CheckAreaTable.Area = AreaTable.Area
                      And CheckAreaTable.User = 'user2')
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just noticed my `'User2'` should have been `'user2'` i.e. obviously watch case sensitivity.

Comment: :) Thats fine. This is just an example of my real scenario. In my real scenario, user is actually userid, a number datatype